# How to add CAST in raw SQL in Entity Framework in .NET Core

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a web app written in .NET Core and I have a post method that receives a parameter and does a query against the database.

```
public IActionResult OnPostGetRegestrationList(string objId)
{       
    List<Flight> data = _context.Flight.FromSqlRaw("select id, side, reg, CAST(Actual_Date as date)as ActDate , CAST(Actual_Time as time)as ActTime from Flight where REG = {0} order by reg, ActDate, ActTime", objId).ToList();
    return new JsonResult(data);
}
```

The query will work if there is no cast but I have to cast so I can get the time in this format '12:49:00.0000000' instead of this format '12/31/1899 12:49:00 PM' which is totally wrong because the date is auto-generated and would give wrong.

How to add `CAST` in SQL raw in Entity Framework, and is adding it to order will give the same result (adding CAST to order is working)? here is a working query but it's not what I want.

```
 List<Flight> data = _context.Flight.FromSqlRaw("select id, side, reg, Actual_Date , Actual_Time from Flight where REG = {0} order by reg, CAST(Actual_Date as date), CAST(Actual_Time as time)", objId).ToList();
```

---

This is the Flight class

```
public class Flight
{
   [Key]
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
    public string REG { get; set; }
    public string Side { get; set; }
    public string Actual_Date { get; set; }
    public string Actual_Time { get; set; }
  
}
```

Class in DB

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Flight](
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[REG] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Side] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Actual_Date] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Actual_Time] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Flight] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: I'm using sql 2019 @jarlh

Comment: Why using raw SQL for such simple thing which can easily be provided by ORM and LINQ? All you need is a proper data type mapping. What is the type of `Actual_Date` and `Actual_Time` columns in database? What is the type of the respective properties in `Flight` class?

Comment: cast  as time(7) ?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `Flight` class definition and the `Flight` table definition. .NET doesn't have a pure Date type (it's DateTime) and the closest thing to a Time type it has is TimeSpan.

Comment: The type of both Actual_Date and Actual_Time is string in DB and in the class @IvanStoev I think SQL raw is faster than LINQ?

Comment: Could you change the datatypes? If so do so. If not create a View which does the type conversion stuff and query against your view. Do not mess up your code with typ conversion stuff and badly designed types because someone did bad design decisions in the past. A date or time should be datetime type and not string in .NET.

Comment: Yes I can do you have any suggestions? @user743414 or just Actual_Date as date and Actual_Time as time(7)

Comment: The best would be to merge Actual_date and Actual_time into one single DB field. In C# you would then just need one property Actual_DateTime. The next best option would be to store both as datetime on the DB.